# CoreWindow::GetCurrentForThread() always NULL

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I'm trying to get the `CoreDispatcher` in C++ on Windows Phone 8 so that I can submit work items to the UI thread Dispatcher so I can update UI elements on the UI thread.  However, when I call `CoreWindow::GetCurrentForThread()`, I get `NULL` back.  In [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.getforcurrentthread) it states that this is supported on WP8.  As long as I'm getting `NULL` for the current Window, I can't get the current `Dispatcher` from it; does anyone know how to get the current Dispatcher on WP8?

Answer (score 2):

`CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()` is documented as returning:

> The `CoreWindow` for the currently active thread.

If you call this function from a thread that does not have a `CoreWindow` (like any non-UI thread), then this function will return `nullptr`.

Assuming the application has finished initializing and there is a view, you can use the dispatcher from the main view of the application via [`CoreApplication::MainView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.mainview).  Alternatively, you can pass the `Dispatcher^` for the UI thread to the code executing on the non-UI thread so that it has access to it when it needs to invoke back onto the UI thread.

Comment: I'm sure I call from the UI thread (from the mouse event). It's still NULL.

Answer (score 2):

I have used

```
await CoreApplication.Views.First().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    //your code here
                });
```