# Obtaining UI dispatcher in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have been developing a Windows Phone application that consumes Windows Runtime component(WRC).A function accessed by a non-UI thread,needs to use a callback that access the Windows phone application.

```
void WControlPointCallback::OnListChange(char *pFriendlyName)
{
    // Callback function to access the UI
    pCallBack->AlertCaller("Message");  
}
```

At first without using the Dispatcher it threw

> `Platform::AccessDeniedException`.

Then I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17244857/2256349), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15153801/2256349) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14497147/2256349).
I tried to obtain the Dispatcher from the UI.

```
var dispatcher = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
```

It threw `System.AccessViolationException`.Then I used

```
pDispatcher = Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->Dispatcher;
```

in C++ code(WRC).But this too throws `Platform::AccessDeniedException`.

How to obtain the Dispatcher for UI in Windows Phone?

Comment: Please don't use `code tags` to emphasize `words` that you think are `important`.  Code tags are for code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't get the dispatcher from C++ for Windows Phone 8: you need to move the call to the UI dispatcher on the C# side, not the C++ side.

If you can just do something like this:

```
class DotNetClass : IWindowsRuntimeInterface
{
    void AlertCaller(string message)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great.Thanks,It saved a lot of time.I stuck up with this issue for nearly two days.